# Mongo driver para php só funciona com mpm_prefork?

Tags: php, apache, desempenho, mongodb

Buscando um melhor desempenho para minha aplicação alterei o *MPM* do *apache* de `prefork` para `event`, porém quando reinicio o apache com o novo módulo de processamento o módulo do *mongodb* não funciona, ao acessar o arquivo de log do *apache* verifiquei a seguinte linha:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mongo.so' - /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Também tentei usar o *MPM* `worker` e reinstalar o drive do *mongo* através do *PECL* inclusive após o comando `pecl clear-cache`, mas a extensão do mongo só funciona com o *MPM* `prefork`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de encontrar minha própria pergunta aqui enquanto buscava a mesma resposta, porém agora com um novo servidor sem usuários a sua espera mergulhei na net em busca de respostas...

Descobri que não tinha haver com o módulo do *MongoDB* e sim com o próprio *PHP* usando o *Apache* com um módulo *MPM* com threads.

Segue o link que resumidamente responde minha pergunta vindo diretamente do manual do *PHP*:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.apache2